# pysolr.SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 409): [Reason: version conflict for expected= actual=]

Tags: python, indexing, solr, pysolr

I am trying to retrieve the documents with a Solr search and then try to add that same document with that same id back into Solr. In doing this, I get a version conflict. Basically i am adding `url` link as shown in the code below.

```
solr = pysolr.Solr('http://**** ', timeout=10)
results = solr.search('resourceType:abc', rows=10)

for res in results:
    if 'url' not in res:
        print("adding...........")
        print(res['id'])
        link = 'https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/' + res['id']
        res['url'] = link
        solr.add(res)
        print(link)
    else:
        print("no need to add")
```

OUTPUT:

```
pysolr.SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 409): [Reason: version conflict for 1402196942545952769 expected=1703466479926640640 actual=1703528530413879296]
```

Comment: i think its failing because you are sending some different version id

Comment: how do i prevent that ?

Comment: The presence of the _version_ field instructs Solr to accept the update only if the document version matches exactly. If you are reading the document from solr and it has _version_ then pass it as along with the updated document

Comment: is it possible for you to share the document from solr which you are trying to update?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186749/error-in-using-solr-to-add-data-solr-http-error-ok-409httpexception#:~:text=If%20there%20is%20a%20version,part%20of%20the%20update%20command.

Comment: Please refer the earlier link...I have already shared the answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in using Solr to add data - Solr HTTP error: OK (409)(HttpException )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186749/error-in-using-solr-to-add-data-solr-http-error-ok-409httpexception)

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti No. Actually i want to know how to i do it in python (Pysolr)